# How to Make Asynchronous Calls in Redux Without Middlewares?

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, react-redux, redux-thunk

I've a simple redux project which makes async call in a function to an external api with fetch api and map over user id by returning a function using redux-thunk middleware. how can I refactor the code without using any middleware ? is it possible in simple way ? I tried reading [this article](https://www.velotio.com/engineering-blog/asynchronous-calls-in-redux-without-middlewares) but got lost.

my redux code -

```
const redux = require("redux");
const createStore = redux.createStore;
const applyMiddleware = redux.applyMiddleware;
const thunkMiddleware = require("redux-thunk").default;
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  users: [],
  error: "",
};

const FETCH_USERS_REQUEST = "FETCH_USERS_REQUEST";
const FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS = "FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS";
const FETCH_USERS_FALIURE = "FETCH_USERS_FALIURE";

const fetchUsersRrequest = () => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERS_REQUEST,
  };
};

const fetchUsersSuccess = (users) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS,
    payload: users,
  };
};

const fetchUsersFaliure = (error) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERS_FALIURE,
    payload: error,
  };
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USERS_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        //...state,
        loading: false,
        users: action.payload,
        error: "",
      };
    case FETCH_USERS_FALIURE:
      return {
        //...state,
        loading: false,
        users: [],
        error: action.payload,
      };
  }
};

const fetchUsers = () => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(fetchUsersRrequest());
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        const users = res.map((user) => user.id);
        console.log(users);
        dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(users));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(fetchUsersFaliure(error.message));
      });
  };
};

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));
store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState());
});
store.dispatch(fetchUsers());
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, in Redux middleware *is* the place for asynchronous logic, so you are essentially asking "how do I drive my car without gas?" and you might get some workaround answers, but they will all boil down to "push it up a hill and let it roll down". It might work, but it really circumvents the problem more than helping ;)

So all I can really do is to  recommend you to read the official tutorials that contain a full chapter around doing exactly that: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic

In general, I'd recommend you start with the official tutorials [from the beginning](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) though, as the code you've been writing up to this point is a very outdated style of redux we don't really recommend writing new applications like that - it's more code to write and harder to learn that old style.

Comment: You are right, I've barely started with redux and did this from a yt tutorial. now my superior at the place of internship asked me if I could do this without middleware and I've scraching my head past 7-8 hours

Comment: Greetings to your superior - I'm a redux maintainer and would really not recommend doing this without middleware. Maybe that helps put it in context for them.
If they go without middleware, I'd usually recommend them to solve the whole thing completely without redux